# Recursive Class header include

Tags: c++, unix, recursion, header-files

I need to include recursively class header files.

#### "Foo.h"

```
#ifndef FOO_H
#define FOO_H
#include "Bar.h"

class Foo {
public:
    Bar* barMember;
};
#endif
```

#### "Bar.h"

```
 #ifndef BAR_H
 #define BAR_H
 #include "Foo.h"
 class Bar {
 public:
     Foo* fooMember;
 };
 #endif
```

In this case I am getting errors like

> 'class' does not name a type

Consider that in this case `Foo` is the main class that includes a lot of other classes as a members. But with one member I need to have bidirectional connection.

So why do I have such problems?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use forward declarations:

```
#ifndef FOO_H
#define FOO_H

class Bar;

class Foo
{
public:
    Bar* barMember;
};
#endif
```

and:

```
#ifndef BAR_H
#define BAR_H

class Foo;

class Bar
{
public:
    Foo* fooMember;
};
#endif
```

You will only need to include the respective header files in the .cpp files containing the implementations, so there won't be mutual inclusions.

Comment: Huh, thanks .. You really saved my hours, I am so exhausted ... Thx again

Comment: Oh, no , again , I don't know what to it gives me a lot of errors. Like Forward declaration ................. I don't know what to do ...